# Installing a Windows Service using SC.exe through C++ coding

Tags: windows, winapi

I am working on a C++ project in VS-2010, i want to install a windows service. My question is whether sc.exe is present in all Windows 7 and Windows 8 by default, and Is it possible to use the below code for installing a service in windows? or what else should i do to achieve it.

```
void CreateService(void) 
{
   system("sc create MyService binPath=c:\\abc.exe");
}
```

looking forward to your kind response.

Comment: Why don't you use the "OpenSCManager" and "CreateService" functions ?

Comment: @JoãoAugusto, why not make that an answer.

Comment: @Ben: I don't know if using the sc is a requirement. :)

Comment: @davidheffernan why??

Comment: It should be avoided at all costs. It's the method of last resort. The OS that you are targeting provides a rich API for handling services. Use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some sample code, just be sure to add proper error checking.

```
SC_HANDLE h_manager = NULL;
SC_HANDLE h_service = NULL;

h_manager = OpenSCManager(NULL, NULL, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);

h_service = CreateServiceW( 
    h_manager,                 // SCM database
    L"MyService",              // name of service
    L"My Service",             // display name
    SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS,        // desired access
    SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS, // service type
    SERVICE_AUTO_START,        // start type
    SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL,      // error control type
    L"c:\\abc.exe",            // path to service's binary
    NULL,                      // no load ordering group
    NULL,                      // no tag identifier
    NULL,                      // no dependencies
    L"NT AUTHORITY\\NetworkService",
    L"");                     // no password

CloseServiceHandle(h_service); 
CloseServiceHandle(h_manager);
```

Links to the documentation:

- [OpenSCManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684323.aspx)
- [CreateService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682450.aspx)
- [CloseServiceHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682028.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to use the `sc` command, you can install the service by calling the `OpenSCManager()` and `CreateService()` functions instead.